# How to set different units for different products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to set different units for different products in WooCommerce?

I want some products to be in grams (gr), and others in milliliters (ml).

Can you recommend a plugin or other way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for minuses and no advices..
I found the solution, plugin WooCommerce Measurement Price Calculator.